# How do i send a message based of a reaction

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i have code that creates a reaction menu then outputs whichever option the user chose

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === 'y.Einek') 
    {
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(Einek);
        const reactions = ['', '', ''];      
        for (const reaction of reactions) await sentMessage.react(reaction);      
        const filter = (reaction, user) => reactions.includes(reaction) && user.id === message.author.id;     
        const collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, timeout: 5000, errors: ['time'] }).catch(() => null);
        if (!collected) return message.channel.send('You either took too long or something went wrong selecting your difficulty.');
        const { name } = collected.first().emoji;
        const response = name === '' ? 'Normal' : (name === '' ? 'Hard' : 'Extreme'); 
        return message.channel.send(response);
    }
});
```

and everything works fine except it doesn't output "response"

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Using the catch method for any error instead.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === 'y.Einek') {
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(Einek);
        const reactions = ['', '', ''];      
        for (const reaction of reactions) await sentMessage.react(reaction);      
        const filter = (reaction, user) => reactions.includes(reaction) && user.id === message.author.id;     
        sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, timeout: 5000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
            const { name } = collected.first().emoji;
            const response = name === '' ? 'Normal' : (name === '' ? 'Hard' : 'Extreme'); 
            sentMessage.channel.send(response);
        }).catch(() => message.channel.send('You either took too long or something went wrong selecting your difficulty.'));
    }
});
```

Comment: no nothing happens when the user selects a reaction